# concatenating numpy arrays from a directory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have multiple numpy arrays (.npy) in a directory. I want to concatenate all of them. I have tried:

```
    files = sorted(glob.glob(r'C:\Users\x\samples' + '/*.npy'))
    for i in range(len(files)):
              data= np.concatenate(files, axis=0)
```

but it gives an error: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated.
any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.concatenate` works on arrays. However, `files` are strings. You should first read the files to obtain arrays:

```
files = sorted(glob.glob(r'C:\Users\x\samples' + '/*.npy'))
arrays = []
for f in files:
    arrays.append(np.load(f))
data = np.concatenate(arrays)
```